# Change width and height of current view in the view pager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

int width = params.width + 20;
            int height = params.height + 240;
            view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height));I basically want to expand the current view in the view pager.

This is what I tried but this doesn't change anything on the current view.

```
 private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener mPageListener = new  ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        View view = mViewPager.findViewWithTag(position);
        if (view == null)
            return;
        view.measure(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        int width = params.width + 20;
        int height = params.height + 240;
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height));
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
};
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What you are using in `youViewPager.setAdapter(..)`?

Comment: simple adapter which is extending FragmentPagerAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
view.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(width, height));
```